# Function to find and replace using wildcard

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wpallimport

How do i completely remove the following strings from my wordpress posts using string replace?

NOTE: These are text strings that got hardcoded when i reimported my posts.
Below are 3 examples however there can be 100s.

Here is the criteria: string starts with:  googletag.cmd.push

String ends with:  "); });

examples:

```
 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-cBdL_cggQrHX7u2qnNrMtQ"); });

 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-y_rI3cXW4HPKVfyNbLcmjg"); });

 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-TOILczxQd6hUhdv1UN5ETA"); });
```

Here is what i tried:

```
 [str_replace("googletag.cmd.push(.*?);", "",{string})]
 [preg_replace("googletag\.cmd\.push\(.*?\); }\);", "<br>", {string})]
```

I am using WP-ALL-Import a wordpress plugin that allows me to execute any PHP function (native functions, or user-defined functions)

http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/execute-php/

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the forward slash. The answer is below:

```
 [preg_replace("/googletag\.cmd\.push\(.*?\); }\);/", "", {string})]
```